# How to check if a value is present in any of given sets

Tags: python, set

Say I have different sets (they have to be different, I cannot join them as per the kind of data I am working with):

```
r = set([1,2,3])
s = set([4,5,6])
t = set([7,8,9])
```

What is the best way to check if a given variable is present in any of them?

I am using:

```
if myvar in r \
   or myvar in s \
   or myvar in t:
```

But I wonder if this can be reduced somehow by using `set`'s properties such as `union`.

The following works, but I can't find a way to define multiple unions:

```
if myvar in r.union(s)
   or myvar in t:
```

I am also wondering if this union will somehow affect performance, since I guess a temporary `set` will be created on the fly.

Comment: I know the title "How to check if a value is present in any of given sets" sounds a bit weird. If anyone sees a better way to write it, please feel free to edit it!

Comment: @ukemi thanks for your corrections. It is funny that the fact that there are more than two elements makes the use of _any_ necessary, and that specific key is the main part of the answer that I got from Padraic :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use any:

```
if any(myvar in x for x in  (r,s,t))
```

set lookups are `0(1)` so creating a union to check if the variable is in any set is totally unnecessary instead of simply checking using `in` with `any` which will short circuit as soon as a match is found and does not create a new set.

*And I am also wondering if this union will affect somehow performance*

Yes of course unioning the sets affects performance, it adds to the complexity, you are creating a new set every time which is `O(len(r)+len(s)+len(t))` so you can say goodbye to the real point of using sets which are efficient lookups.

So the bottom line is that is you want to keep efficient lookups you will have to union the set once and keep them in memory creating a new variable then using that to do your lookup for `myvar` so the initial creation will be `0(n)` and lookups will be `0(1)` thereafter.

If you don't every time you want to do a lookup first creating the union you will have a linear solution in the length of `r+s+t -> set.union(*(r, s, t))` as opposed to at worst three constant(on average) lookups. That also means always adding or removing any elements from the new unioned set that are added/removed from `r,s` or `t`.

Some realistic timings on  moderately large sized sets show exactly the difference:

```
In [1]: r = set(range(10000))

In [2]: s = set(range(10001,20000))

In [3]: t = set(range(20001,30000))

In [4]: timeit any(29000 in st for st in (r,s,t))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 869 ns per loop  

In [5]: timeit 29000 in r | s | t
1000 loops, best of 3: 956 µs per loop

In [6]: timeit 29000 in reduce(lambda x,y :x.union(y),[r,s,t])
1000 loops, best of 3: 961 µs per loop

In [7]: timeit 29000 in r.union(s).union(t)
1000 loops, best of 3: 953 µs per loop
```

Timing the union shows that pretty much all the time is spent in the union calls:

```
In [8]: timeit r.union(s).union(t)
1000 loops, best of 3: 952 µs per loop
```

Using larger sets and getting the element in the last set:

```
In [15]: r = set(range(1000000))

In [16]: s = set(range(1000001,2000000))

In [17]: t = set(range(2000001,3000000))


In [18]: timeit any(2999999 in st for st in (r,s,t))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 878 ns per loop

In [19]: timeit 2999999 in reduce(lambda x,y :x.union(y),[r,s,t])
1 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [20]: timeit 2999999 in r | s | t
10 loops, best of 3: 157 ms per loop
```

There is literally no difference no matter how large the sets get using `any` but as the set sizes grow so does the running time using union.

The only way to make it faster would be to stick to `or` but we are taking the difference of a few hundred nanoseconds which is the cost of creating the generator expression and the function call:

```
In [22]: timeit 2999999 in r or 2999999 in s or 2999999 in t
10000000 loops, best of 3: 152 ns per loop
```

To union sets set.union(*(r, s, t)) is also the fastest as you don't build intermediary sets:

```
In [47]: timeit 2999999 in set.union(*(r,s,t))
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
In [49]: r | s | t  == set.union(*(r,s,t))
Out[49]: True
```

Comment: So the performance is very bad if I do use `union`, whereas using `any()` will be faster?

Comment: @fedorqui, if you create a set, it is  `0(n)`  n obviously  being the length of your set. If you have to do that every time you want to lookup myvar you now have a to create a set which involves going over the length of `r+s+t` ever before you do a lookup so what could be three constant lookups using `any` is now a linear operation.

Comment: @fedorqui using any is a good recipe but in this case `value in r|s|t ` is faster! checkout my answer for benchmark!

Comment: @Kasra, your tests are rather pointless, I doubt the OP or anyone else is worried about the tmie it takes for three 3 element sets

Comment: @PadraicCunningham indeed that its like so as is said in my answer its just for **this case** any way i must said that for large sets `any` is better.i'll add it to my answer. also thanks for pointing that!

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that the use of a generator expression with `any` allows lazy evaluation. This is important in cases where you have 1000s of sets. `any` can then stop after the first set that fulfills the `myvar in x` constraint without evaluating any further sets. If you were to use `any([myvar in s for s in your_sets])` instead, you wouldn't have that advantage as it would first have to generate the list of booleans for all sets, only to realize that any will jump out after the first True at position 3 for example.

Answer (score 16):

You can use builtin [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
r = set([1,2,3])
s = set([4,5,6])
t = set([7,8,9])
if any(myvar in x for x in [r,s,t]):
    print "I'm in one of them"
```

`any` will short circuit on the first condition that returns `True` so you can get around constructing a potentially huge `union` or checking potentially lots of sets for inclusion.

*And I am also wondering if this union will affect somehow performance, since I guess a temporary set will be created on the fly.*

According to [wiki.python.com](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) `s|t` is `O(len(s)+len(t))` while lookups are `O(1)` .

For `n` sets with `l` elements each , doing `union` iteratively to construct the set will result in:

```
a.union(b).union(c).union(d) .... .union(n)
```

Which is equivalent to `O(l+l)` for `a.union(b)` and `O(2l+2l+l)` `a.union(b).union(c)` and so on which sums up to `O(n*(n+1)/2)*l)`.

`O(n^2*l)` is quadratic and voids the performance advantage of using sets.

The lookup in n sets with `any` will perform at `O(n)`

Comment: I am very grateful to your answer also. It is a pity so many good answers appeared in the same question, I would've like to accept them all :)

Comment: FWIW, `union` is variadic which can simplify the chain (and asymptotic times).

Answer (score 5):

`|` is a union operator of `sets` in python. You can define union over multiple sets using `|` as:

```
>>> r = set([1,2,3])
>>> s = set([4,5,6])
>>> t = set([7,8,9])
>>> r | s | t
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: So `r | s | t` is the way to have multiple `union` together. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function to *apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable*:

```
>>> r = set([1,2,3])
>>> s = set([4,5,6])
>>> t = set([7,8,9])
>>> 
>>> reduce(lambda x,y :x.union(y),[r,s,t])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

And for checking the membership in either of them you can use a generator expression within [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) that is more efficient here because python use [*hash table*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHash_table&ei=3DlsVf-6G8m0UcyIgJAI&usg=AFQjCNFWP9iBvqhV_h73-y04O6NM6tIsNQ&sig2=zf5JLZoZ4skJN-Mmw4l9Bw) for storing the sets and checking the member ship has O(1) in such data structures like dictionaries or `frozenset`.Also for check the membership in all of you sets use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

```
if any(i in item for item in [r,s,t]):
    #do stuff
```

But in this case (**Not for large sets**) using `or` operator is faster.

```
value in r|s|t
```

This is a benchmark on all the ways :

```
~$ python -m timeit "r = set([1,2,3]);s = set([4,5,6]);t = set([7,8,9]);3 in reduce(lambda x,y :x.union(y),[r,s,t])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "r = set([1,2,3]);s = set([4,5,6]);t = set([7,8,9]);3 in r|s|t"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "r = set([1,2,3]);s = set([4,5,6]);t = set([7,8,9]);any(3 in item for item in [r,s,t])"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit "r = set([1,2,3]);s = set([4,5,6]);t = set([7,8,9]);3 in r.union(s).union(t)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 usec per loop
```

*Note* that as @Padraic Cunningham mentioned **for large sets using a `any` is very much efficient**!

Comment: Creating the generator expression and the function call probably takes more time as anything, testing three 3 element sets does not give an accurate picture of just how inefficient it is to union. –

Comment: Thanks for showing me the `reduce` function, didn't know about it. Will keep it in mind for future reference :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham indeed that its like so as is said in my answer its just for **this case** any way i must said that for large sets `any` is better.i'll add it to my answer. also thanks for pointing that!

Comment: "`reduce(lambda x,y :x.union(y),[r,s,t])`" → ...Or just `set().union(r, s, t)`. FWIW I'm downvoting because - although technically correct - this is not a good idea.

Comment: @Veedrac Its just a suggestion that for apply a function cumulatively to the items of iterable.also i explained the benefits of other recipes after that!

Comment: @Kasra It might be "just a suggestion", but it's still a bad one.

Comment: @Veedrac The benchmark does it perfectly!and you can keep your down vote but just remember that don't repeat such behavior against another answers!

Comment: @Kasra wrt. your benchmarks - you're timing the setup as well as the execution. [Here's a fixed version.](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/c343f3c2b0a2a563658a)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

`if myvar in r.union(s).union(t)`

And you needn't worry about performance here. Yes it creates a temporary set on the fly but as it isn't stored gets garbage collected.

Comment: Interesting! So it will be garbage collected as soon as it gets checked.

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, as soon as there are no references to the created object it gets garbage collected. And in this case as it union is not stored in any variable there are no references to it after the statement call.