# Set difference versus set subtraction

Tags: python, set, subtraction, set-difference

What distinguishes `-` and `.difference()` on sets? Obviously the syntax is not the same. One is a binary operator, and the other is an instance method. What else?

```
s1 = set([1,2,3])
s2 = set([3,4,5])

>>> s1 - s2
set([1, 2])
>>> s1.difference(s2)
set([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

`set.difference, set.union...` can take *any iterable* as the second arg  while both need to be sets to use `-`, there is no difference in the output.

```
Operation         Equivalent   Result
s.difference(t)   s - t        new set with elements in s but not in t
```

With .difference you can do things like:

```
s1 = set([1,2,3])

print(s1.difference(*[[3],[4],[5]]))

{1, 2}
```

It is also more efficient when creating sets using the `*(iterable,iterable)` syntax as you don't create intermediary sets, you can see some comparisons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571285/how-to-check-if-a-value-is-present-in-any-of-given-sets/30571351#30571351)

Comment: I guess the next question is... why?
Why isn't set subtraction defined to be the same as set difference?

Comment: @user48956 `set_a - set_b` is defined by the magic (or dunder) method, `__sub__` and is equivalent to `set_a.__sub__(set_b)`. As such, the difference operator is dependent on the class of the leftmost object. From there, it's all implementation details, however obscure, like those in the answer of @Abhijit

Answer (score 26):

At a glance, it may not be quite evident from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), but buried deep inside a paragraph it is dedicated to differentiate the method call with the operator version:

> Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(),
> difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset()
> methods will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their
> operator based counterparts require their arguments to be sets. This
> precludes error-prone constructions like `set('abc') & 'cbs'` in favor
> of the more readable `set('abc').intersection('cbs')`.

Answer (score 19):

The documentation appears to suggest that difference can take multiple sets, so it is possible that it might be more efficient and clearer for things like:

```
s1 = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
s2 = set([2, 5])
s3 = set([3, 6])
s1.difference(s2, s3) # instead of s1 - s2 - s3
```

but I would suggest some testing to verify.